# Is $\bar X$ a minimum variance unbiased estimator of $\theta$ in an exponential distribution?

Tags: statistics

I proceeded by finding $\operatorname E(\bar X).$ I considered $\bar X$ as a constant and simply got the term itself. This should suggest that $\bar X$ is not an unbiased estimator of $\theta$. That's obvious too cuz it's a constant(from what I assumed). However, I'm also aware that $\mu = \theta$ so that's probably not right. 
I have to demonstrate first that $\bar X$ is an unbiased estimator of $\mu$.

Comment: For an exponential distribution with mean $\theta$, the sample mean $\bar X$ *is* the UMVUE of $\theta$. How can $\bar X$ be a constant?

Comment: Forgot to add a comment in parenthesis. Sorry. However, if you're seriously asking 
 me, I have no clue cuz I'm just starting out. But what you mentioned is what I have to prove.

Comment: I think you're confused about 'means' and 'constants'. The _sample_ mean $\bar X$ is a random variable (incidentally, having a gamma distribution, when the data are exponential) and the _population_ mean $\mu$ is an unknown constant (within the framework of this frequentist estimation problem). // It doesn't matter that the population mean has two notations here $\mu = \theta.$ // Unaddressed in Question and Comments so far is how we know that $\bar X$ is UMVUE for $\mu.$ You say you showed it's unbiased, but not why it has minimum variance.

Comment: See [_this page_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034206/finding-umvue-of-theta-when-the-underlying-distribution-is-exponential-distri) for a related discussion including UMVUE, but beware of a difference in notation. The link uses $\theta = 1/\mu.$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the underlying population is exponential with mean $\theta$, i.e. with density $$f(x;\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}\,\mathbb I(x)\quad,\theta>0$$

where $\mathbb I(x)=\begin{cases}1&,\text{ if }x>0\\0&,\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$.

$(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)$ is a random sample drawn from the above population.

Then, $\displaystyle\mathbb E_{\theta}(\bar X)=\mathbb E_{\theta}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb E_{\theta}(X_i)=\frac{n\theta}{n}=\theta$ for all $\theta$.

So as usual we see that the sample mean $\bar X$ is unbiased for the population mean $\theta$.

Now, the joint density of $(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)$ is \begin{align}f_{\theta}(\mathbf x)&=\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i;\theta)\\&=\frac{1}{\theta^n}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb I(x_i)\\\implies \ln f_{\theta}(\mathbf x)&=-n\ln \theta-\frac{1}{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+\sum_{i=1}^n\ln \mathbb I(x_i)\\\implies\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln f_{\theta}(\mathbf x)&=\frac{-n}{\theta}+\frac{n\bar x}{\theta^2}\\&=\frac{n}{\theta^2}\left(\bar x-\theta\right)\end{align}

Thus we have expressed the score function in the form

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln f_{\theta}(\mathbf x)=k(\theta)(T(\mathbf x)-\theta)\tag{1}$$

which is the equality condition in the Cramér-Rao inequality.

Hence we see that

- $\bar X$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$.
- $\bar X$ is the statistic $T(\mathbf X)$ which satisfies the equality condition $(1)$ of the Cramér-Rao inequality. That is, variance of $\bar X$ attains the Cramér-Rao lower bound for $\theta$.

These two facts imply that $\bar X$ is the UMVUE of $\theta$.

---

Here we have exploited a corollary of the Cramér-Rao inequality, which says that for a family of distributions parametrised by $\theta$ (assuming regularity conditions of Cramér-Rao inequality to hold), if a statistic $T$ is unbiased for $\theta$ and if it satisfies $(1)$, then $T$ must be the uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimator of $\theta$. This holds for a function of $\theta$ also. Needless to say, this does not work in every problem. In all those cases, one has to use the theory of completeness and sufficiency as mentioned in the other answer.

If you want to do this problem the usual way, you would have to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a complete sufficient statistic for the family of distributions, and that $\bar X$, a function of the complete sufficient statistic, is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$. So by the Lehmann-Scheffé theorem, $\bar X$ is the UMVUE of $\theta$.

Comment: Great proof. So I did the same thing except I didn't find the product of $f(x_i;\theta)$ (that's how my textbook Math. Stat. & application by Freud explains it). Which is why possibly my calculation of the variance has an n in the denominator.

Comment: @thevader.java For the purpose of finding the Fisher information in many problems, it is easier to start with a single observation, and then multiplying the information for the single observation by $n$ to get the  information for the set of observations. But here we don't require the Fisher information nor the CR lower bound. We have to work with the joint density .

Comment: That $\sum X_i$ is complete sufficient follows from the fact that the pdf $f$ is a member of the one-parameter exponential family.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
\bar X = \frac{ X_1+\cdots+X_n } n
$$
and for every measurable $A\subseteq[0,\infty)^n,$
$$
\Pr((X_1,\ldots,X_n) \in A) = \int_A e^{-x_1/\theta} \cdots e^{-x_n/\theta} \, \frac{d(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}{\theta^n}.
$$
The density is $\dfrac{e^{-(x_1\,+\,\cdots\,+\,x_n)/\theta}}{\theta^n}.$ The fact that the density depends on $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ only through $x_1+\cdots+x_n$ is sufficient (but not necessary) to show that $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta,$ i.e. the conditional distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ given $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ does not depend on $\theta.$

That $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is a complete statistic means that there only the identically zero function $g$ satisfies the condition
$$
\int_{[0,\infty)^n} g(x_1+\cdots+x_n) e^{-(x_1+\cdots+x_n)/\theta} \,\left(\frac{d(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}{\theta^n}\right) \text{ remains equal to $0$ as $\theta\ge0$ changes}.
$$

Comment: So I can't tell if your work is right(We haven't been taught this method yet). However, we're instructed to use the Cramer–Rao inequality. Result is, $\frac {d(ln(f(x))}{d\theta} $ =${ x - \theta \over \theta^2}$. Then I went ahead and used this for finding the variance of $\bar X $. I have $\theta^2$ but I'm still left with an n in the denominator.