# $ f(x|\theta)=2x\theta e^{-\theta x^2}I_{(0,\infty)}(x)\hspace{0.5cm}\theta\in\mathbb{R}^+ $UMVUE for $h(\theta)=1/\theta$ and $h(\theta)=\theta$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X$ a random sample with density function $$f(x|\theta)=2x\theta e^{-\theta x^2}I_{(0,\infty)}(x)\hspace{0.5cm}\theta\in\mathbb{R}^+$$

Then
$$f_\theta(\vec{x})=\left(2^n\prod
_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\theta^n\exp{-\theta\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}\hspace{0.5cm}\underset{\forall i=1,\dots,n}{x_i,\theta\in\mathbb{R}^+}$$
It belongs to the exponential family and
$$T(X)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2$$ is a minimal statistic for $\theta$

Question 1):
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\ln f_\theta(\vec{x})=-\left[T-\frac{n}{\theta}\right]=-n\left[\frac{T}{n}-\frac{1}{\theta}\right]$$
Then $T$ is an efficent statistic for $h(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}$, so is T the UMVUE for $1/\theta?$

Question 2) How can I find the UMVUE for $\theta $ ?

Thank you

Comment: Note that $Y=X^2$ is exponential with rate $\theta$, so both are answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2034206/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2819978/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thank you so much, how do you know $Y\sim Exp(\theta)$?  I tried to use a change of variable but  it doesn`t work

Comment: Try again.$\quad$